# Proving inequalities with ratios

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, ratio

Prove that $(a^2 + b^2)(x^2 + y^2) \geq (ax + by)^2$, with equality if and only if $a: b = x: y$.

I have tried proof by induction but am stuck as I am confused on how to use ratios.  I have also expanded the brackets:

$$a^2x^2 + a^2y^2 + b^2x^2 + b^2y^2 \geq a^2x^2 + 2abxy + b^2y^2.$$

Now, I have simplified my expansion to $(ay-bx)(ay-bx) \geq 0$

I have also realised that, for $(ay-bx)(ay-bx) \geq 0$, $(ay-bx)$ must be either greater than, less than or equal to $0$.

In the first case, $ay>bx$.  In the second case, $ay<bx$ and in the third case, $ay=bx$

Yet again, the ratios stump me.

How can I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: This is Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: **Hint:** If you simplify your expansion, it is just $(ay-bx)^2\geqslant0$. Now when can equality be possible? Does that give you a condition in terms of $x/y$?